# Styling Mult Index Pandas

Tags: python, html, css, dataframe, styling

I would like to have a background color for my first level in my multi index. But with my code I selected all multi index. Do you have an idea to select just the first level and put a different background color ? ('Top 20 Best Performer MTD MSCI EMU Small & Mid Cap in EUR')

```
d1 = dict(selector="th.col_heading", props=[('text-align', 'center'),('background-color', '#1db2ea'),('color','white'),('font-size', '11px')] )

df_mdt_best.style.set_table_styles([d1])
```

[image: Output DataFrame]

Comment: i find this : d1 = dict(selector="th.col_heading:nth-child(2)", props=[('text-align', 'center'),('background-color', '#1db2ea'),('color','white'),('font-size', '11px')] )

Comment: But it seleted the first level and 'Company Name'